# VS starts IE in compatibility mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 always starts IE in compatibility mode. Is it possible to run ie10 instead from VS?

Comment: If your Target Scheme dropdown set to HTML 4.01, maybe?

Comment: Ok.  No idea.  That was a guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to click the compatibility icon in the adress bar to turn the mode off. Turning it off in debugging tools does not save the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a setting in IE 
Goto Internet Options>Advanced>Browsing,
there is a setting , `Automatically recover from page layout errors with Compatibility` 
Maybe if that is checked , that could be causing IE to start in Compatibility Mode.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.
Bug reported to developers at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2723548-open-links-in-an-actual-browser Please add your vote!

Also it's worth noting that the internal VS browser is actually using the IE7 compat rendering engine instead of the machine installed IE.

see Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591116/visual-web-developer-internal-browser-browser-standard